Classify rows into different groups based on amount
I want to divide these below rows into 3 groups:

Group 1 including Company A and Company B with very large amount
Group 2 including Company C,D,E,F with medium amount
Group 3 including Company G,H,I with very small amount

How can I do it using SQL?



Company Name
Amount




Company A
1,000,000


Company B
500,000


Company C
5,000


Company D
3,000


Company E
2,000


Company F
1,000


Company G
60


Company H
30


Company I
20




Please define very large amount, medium amount, very small amount,and include desired output, because GROUP BY is a standard SQL functionality, which has already many questions and answers... (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+GROUP+BY+)

We can use the STRING_AGG() function along with CASE expressions:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN Amount < 1000 THEN 'small'
             WHEN Amount < 100000 THEN 'medium'
             ELSE 'large' END AS grp
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT grp, STRING_AGG(Company, ',') AS companies
FROM cte
GROUP BY grp;


I might be spoiled, but I consider < 2000 smal ...... So, how is this an answer to this question ?

It depends on the currency being used.  Zimbabwe dollars are not the same as Pound Sterling.

@Luuk The question was about how to build groups depending on the amount and this question is totally answered. In my opinion, your comment is absolutely useless because OP will certainly be able to change the amounts if they want.

Tim & Jonas, You are thinking for the question asker, and I ask a (return-)question to make the asker think about his own problem.  when he did define a column containing the group in which it belongs, he could have answered his own question. But, in stead, he started asking , (and stopped thinking )

Good answer, but the explanation could be better focused on the creation of a category (grp) column rather than the use of STRING_AGG(). The category can be defined using a common table expression (as above), nested query, or CROSS APPLY. (Personally, I prefer the latter, when just calculating extra values.) This fiddle shows the three approaches.

For diversity
with groups as(
  select * from(
   values ('large',500000,null)
         ,('medium',1000,50000)
         ,('small',0,1000))t(GroupName,FromValue,UpToValue)
)
select t.*
  ,g.groupName
from test t
left join groups g 
  on t.amount >=FromValue 
    and (t.amount<UpToValue or UpToValue is null)




CompanyName
Amount
GroupName




Company A
1000000
large


Company B
500000
large


Company C
5000
medium


Company D
3000
medium


Company E
2000
medium


Company F
1000
medium


Company F
1000
small


Company G
60
small


Company H
30
small


Company I
20
small



fiddle
